# Algebraic elimination: Subtracting one equation from another

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm studying basic polynomial math online and I ran into this situation:

$$\begin{cases}2a + b = 8 \\
 a + b = 5\end{cases}$$

The course material infers, using this exact notation, that:

$$2a + b = 8 - (a + b = 5) = a = 3$$

I was staring at this for a while and couldn't put it together, and then I realized that:
$$\begin{cases}(2a-a) + (b-b) = 8-5\\
             a = 3\end{cases}$$

This all seems logical but what I wonder is: Why can you do this? I've been rooting around the net but I can't seem to find the relevant name for this. I think it's called elimination but I don't know what branch of mathematics it falls under.

Comment: This is the standard method to solve linear equation systems. The Gauss-algorithm precises the method. If the equations are satisfied, the difference of the equations is an equation that must also be satisfied because the values left and right are equal. Inserting the solution into the original equations approves that the solution is actually right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about substitution, that it always is allowed to replace equal expressions with each other. That's the essential property of equality.

Since $2a+b=8$ and $a+b=5$, the substitutions are allowed:

$a=(2a+b)-(a+b)=8-5$